# Total number of superuser users...

Tags: support, api, data-explorer

Hi all,

I am probably doing something wrong but there seems to be a discrepancy between the data-explorer and the API.  For instance,

This query has a total of 48048.
http://api.superuser.com/1.0/users?sort=reputation&order=desc&pagesize=100&page=1

But the data-explorer has a total of 58630

http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/new using select count(*) from users;

Am I missing something here?  Is there a difference between registered and non-registered maybe?

Cheers,

Slothishtype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/users` route only returns registered users, as was (at the time of 1.0) the behavior of the equivalent route on the sites themselves.